# IS there any program/way of emulating an arduino serial port and monitoring what is being sent

Tags: c++, arduino, processing, communication

I'm programming quite a lot with arduino and processing. And i usually aren't able to take my arduino setup with me at all times.

So that means that i have to comment out a lot of stuff from my processing sketch (things like .write and setups for serial stuff) so that the code will run.

And i was thinking if there's a way to emulate an arduino on one of the com ports and also a way to monitor the data that is being sent.

Comment: http://arduinodev.com/codeblocks/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your low level differences between the following pragma.

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) 
  Serial.print...
#else
  .. Processing way..
#endif
```